# Can't boot Ubuntu 18.04 LTE to desktop after upgrade to 4.15.0-51

Tags: 18.04, grub2, vmware, xrandr

I have a VM running Ubuntu 18.04. After an upgrade (looks like it was to Kernel 4.15.0-51) I can't boot to the desktop. Instead, I see a blank, reddish screen.

If I use Grub to get a recovery mode, I can boot to the desktop just fine. I've read elsewhere that this indicates a display driver problem, but I can't find a way to install any 3rd party drivers ... I don't think VMWare needs special drivers anyway, does it?

I've modified grub to not have the "quiet" or "splash" options, but I still don't see any specific error message. I end up what might be the splash screen -- it's graphical, not a terminal window -- but it has no content.

I performed the update as usual, with the GUI "Software Updater".

The only other choice in Grub is the  4.15.0-50 Kernel. It has the same behaviour.

I eventually found a way to get the log files from a previous boot. Here's the last few things I see in the log that seem to be from before the blank screen is shown:

```
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 spice-vdagent[1483]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 boltd[1477]: bolt 0.5 starting up.
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 boltd[1477]: config: loading user config
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 boltd[1477]: bouncer: initializing polkit
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 boltd[1477]: udev: initializing udev
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 boltd[1477]: store: loading devices
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 boltd[1477]: power: force power support: no
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 boltd[1477]: udev: enumerating devices
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 dbus-daemon[955]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.bolt'
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 systemd[1]: Started Thunderbolt system service.
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 gnome-session[1259]: gnome-session-binary[1259]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited wit
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 gnome-session-binary[1259]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 PackageKit[1478]: daemon start
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 dbus-daemon[955]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Jun 14 12:59:22 ubuntu16 systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Jun 14 12:59:23 ubuntu16 gnome-shell[1357]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUn
Jun 14 12:59:23 ubuntu16 gnome-shell[1357]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js 1477]: reference
Jun 14 12:59:23 ubuntu16 gnome-session-binary[1259]: Entering running state
Jun 14 12:59:23 ubuntu16 xbrlapi.desktop[1569]: openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
Jun 14 12:59:23 ubuntu16 xbrlapi.desktop[1569]: cannot connect to braille devices daemon brltty at :0
Jun 14 12:59:23 ubuntu16 gsd-color[1491]: failed to get edid: unable to get EDID for output
Jun 14 12:59:23 ubuntu16 gsd-color[1491]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual-1: unable to get EDID for output
Jun 14 12:59:46 ubuntu16 dbus-daemon[955]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_time
Jun 14 12:59:47 ubuntu16 systemd-timesyncd[664]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun 14 13:04:02 ubuntu16 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
```

I guess this means that grub can't figure out what it needs to know about the display driver. But I've not a clue how to fix that, or why a pushed upgrade would break it.

Any advice?

Comment: Thanks @Nmath ! I've made some edits to my question with the details I have. Unfortunately, I don't see any error messages -- just a blank screen -- despite my attempt to enable the display of kernel messages at boot.  I haven't a clue of how to tell what display adapter I have in the VM. The host is running Windows 10 with an Nvidia GeForce GTX 970.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling Wayland by modifying `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`:

- Create a backup of the file:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/gdm3/custom.conf /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.old
  ```
- Open `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` in a text editor:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
  ```
- Uncomment the line `WaylandEnable=false` by deleting the preceding `#`
- Save the file <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
- Reboot the system.

Once I disabled Wayland, my VM is again usable on the first boot without having to use recovery mode.

This issue is being tracked as [Login screen never appears on vmwgfx but installing kernel >= v4.17-rc1 (or using WaylandEnable=false) fixes it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1832138) on launchpad.net.

Comment: I didn't remove Wayland; I disabled it. I had to do so because it's broken. If Wayland isn't enabled, the GNOME desktop goes back to using X ... which works.

It would've been hard for things to be more broken than they were before this fix. I mean, I guess I could've lost data, but my machine was certainly unusable. With Wayland disabled and GNOME now using X, I'm back to where I was before this update broke me.

I'm sorry that you don't like the way that I posted my solution.