# Ubuntu 18.04 login page freezes, not entering tty

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, python3, tty

Cannot log into Ubuntu. Recently removed python3, regretting it, restarted a computer and cannot enter the system. Not reacting to inputs at all,  cannot switch to tty as well.
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Do you get to a login prompt? What happens if you use grub to enter recovery mode? There was a recent update that caused a problem with GNOME starting correct, so maybe you're having problems with that.

Comment: Yes, I do get a login prompt, but after several carret flashes on password field, everything freezes.

Comment: Recovery mode works fine, but what do I recover from?

Comment: Does this issue match your symptoms? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151137/cant-boot-ubuntu-18-04-lte-to-desktop-after-upgrade-to-4-15-0-51

Answer (score 0):

You can install python3 in 2 ways.
1. Boot from live USB and then [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) into your installation and install python3.
2. From the grub menu, you can also go into the recovery and then try to recover it.

Comment: I managed to reinstall python3 through recovery mode root shell, but the problem remains