# Night light icon shows up - but desktop colors don't change

Tags: 20.04, unity, display, night-light

I'm using a manual schedule for night light - and right now I'm within the schedule. Using Ubuntu 20.04

I see the 'Night light' icon in my status bar - and clicking it shows 'Night light is on', but my actual colors are still as bright as usual.

Dragging the slider from less <> more warm also has no effect on the screen color.

`tail /var/log/syslog` shows this:

```
Aug 16 02:11:49 beast gsd-color[1974]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output
Aug 16 02:11:51 beast gsd-color[1974]: message repeated 30 times: [ unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output]
Aug 16 02:11:52 beast gnome-shell[1650]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
Aug 16 02:11:52 beast gsd-color[1974]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output
Aug 16 02:11:57 beast gsd-color[1974]: message repeated 31 times: [ unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output]
```

I'm guessing  `unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output` has something to do with what's wrong - but googling it hasn't led to anything useful.

Any ideas what that error is talking about?

Comment: I'm not saying this is the answer, but it might be related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151137/cant-boot-ubuntu-18-04-lte-to-desktop-after-upgrade-to-4-15-0-51

Comment: Have you tried using Redshift?

Comment: @mchid No, would that help with this? Changing my brightness settings is having no effect

Comment: @ClickUpvote Redshift seems to work well. Sometimes there is a similar issue but you just have to reinstall some geolocate package mentioned in the error when it occurs. However, I'm not sure if redshift supports wayland so you might have to use xorg (I think I just solved your question).

Answer (score 1):

`xrandr` is not used or supported by Wayland.

If you can, [log in using xorg instead of Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/a/961345/167115). Hopefully, this is still an option.